# How to pass instance variable as argument which can persist in function for multiple calls?

Tags: python, malware

I'm using [Androguard](http://code.google.com/p/androguard/) to analyze some malware files. Currently I'm trying to get [androsim.py](http://code.google.com/p/androguard/source/browse/androsim.py) to analyze a file with its entire directory. The objective is to iterate over all folders where in each folder you compare files with the other files in your folder.

I'm not able to get androsim running in another script, one of the arguments to the main function is an instance variable, whose value is transient and the code breaks?

```
import androsim
import sys, os

from optparse import OptionParser  
from androsim import options 
parser = OptionParser() 
for option in options :
   param = option['name']
   del option['name']
   parser.add_option(*param, **option)

options, arguments = parser.parse_args()
sys.argv[:] = arguments
print options,arguments

androsim.main(options, arguments)
```

Comment: By "multiple calls" do you mean "calls to the function within a single execution of the script" or "calls to the main function across repeated execution of the script"?

Comment: calls to the main function across repeated execution of the script

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're after here, but if the instance object you have is mutating between passing it into the function and using it, then make a copy of it and pass the copy in instead:

```
from copy import deepcopy
intransient = deepcopy(options)

androsim.main(intransient, arguments)
```